# Does duplication happen quicker than generation?

Tags: unity, c#

I am evaluating performance of bullet instantiation methods in Unity. I have a thing against prefabs. So each bullet is made from a function that sets the shape material, scripts and behaviors (tracking, velocity, duration, etcetera). Call this the "ammo type" if you like. Here are my instantiation methods:

1. Generate one bullet from script.  Disable it. Instantiate(duplicate) new bullets from this bullet and enable them when gun fires.
2. Each time the gun fires, generate a new bullet from the script. Still technically a duplicate but arrived at through a different method.

Which of these would have better performance? Would it be a drastic difference or a minor one?

The first method makes much more sense than the second. However there is a problem with delegates not being transferred when duplicating. Thus I am considering the second method and wondering how bad it would be on performance.

For more information on the problem with delegates when duplicating a prefab read [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/instantiate-and-copying-delegates-strange-bug.195961/).

I am happy to clarify any of the above should you find my explanation lacking.

Comment: Try and profile both?

Comment: You considered pooling?

Comment: There's an easy workaround to the delegate duplication problem if you need: just give your bullet script a Clone() method that internally Instantiates its object then copies its delegate into the new instance before returning it.